# Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit rg.jboss.msc.service.StartException

Tags: ejb, wildfly-8

I am new to programming EJB. I gotta figure out why I am getting the error. The following link contains the entire project, the error message (server.log) and the instructions of the project (in spanish).  The pdf file has a sql script to create the database in PostGreSQL
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByDcdmGZJObUMFVtaEQ2ZnduNUU

I basically need to be able to insert a new user (cuidadano) that lives in a city(cuidad) and provincia(province).  When selecting  the province, the second drop down should only show the cities under the province. I am using "wildfly-8.1.0.Final" is my application server program.

I need to get this right asap for a class i am taking.  My final grade depends on it. thanks!

Comment: You should post your code here and read [mcve].

Comment: I forgot to mention i have reviewed other answers but havent helped me. I know it is not a problem of connection to the database because from the wildfly administration panel i am testing the  data source connection and it working. i get a "Successfully created JDBC connection"

Answer (score 0):

In your server.log there is

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.ejb.entidades.Provincia.ciudades[com.ejb.entidades.Ciudad]
```

Try analyzing the class Ciudad and the annotation you used there, expecially @OneToMany and @ManyToMany with reference to classes that are not managed (not marked as Entity or with other JPA annotations)